# how to work modal using external js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote some javascript code to show a modal after page load and click a button to redirect another url. That worked fine. But now I need it to be done with an external javascript file. Thanks in advance. Here is what I did:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Pop Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Here is your message Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Here is your message details</p>

                    <a  href="https://www.fiverr.com/" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Exit</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I do this with an external javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new file with '.js' extension.
example: create 'scripts.js'

and write  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});

$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
});
```

and then in the html file before  add:

you need to add correct file to the file in 'src' attribute'.

Comment: $(".modal") will not find anything as shown since file is in head

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything in you `<script>` tag and put it in an external js file. You can link this file in your html with the following:

```
<script src="js/YourJSFile.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');

    $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
    });

});
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Pop Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/YourJSFile.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Here is your message Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Here is your message details</p>

                    <a  href="https://www.fiverr.com/" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Exit</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(".modal")` will not find anything as shown since file is in head

Answer (score 0):

script "the js file" must be add just before the closing body tag